# I want to get XML tag value lat and long and event description and print those point on shape file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

http://www.massdot.state.ma.us/feeds/MARoadwayEventsXML.aspx

```
import arcpy
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

xmlD = etree.parse("C:\data.xml")
root = xmlD.getroot()
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: my question is to parse the following tags from the XML file in the link to list or dict then polotting into shape file with arcgis.Thank you<EventSubType>pothole</EventSubType><PrimaryLatitude>42.80583</PrimaryLatitude>
<PrimaryLongitude>-71.03337</PrimaryLongitude>

Comment: That's not a question, that's just what you want to do (its a statement of the problem). What do you need help with? You posted some code, does it not work? What error do you get?

Comment: i need help finding a code than i can use to extract those tags from the xml file and store them into shapfile or list.i get one value using root.children but not all of them.

Comment: Please read the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out what kind of questions you should ask here. It looks like you are looking for people to do some work for you.